# $scope.push failing to update after entering same value in Angular (bug!)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am new to Angular and I was trying my hands on a few functions. I found this strange behavior when I try to re-enter the same value.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<body ng-app="angular-test">
  <div ng-controller="FormController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <form ng-submit="addName()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="newName">
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

/*** Angular Code ***/
(function() {
var app = angular.module("angular-test", []);
  app.controller("FormController",formController);

    function formController($scope){
      $scope.names = ['Israel','Agyeman','Prempeh','Osei','Apea'];
      $scope.addName = function(){            
        $scope.names.push($scope.newName);
        $scope.newName = '';
    }
   }
})(angular);
```

![A list generated from the existing model in the HTML page][1]

- Israel
- Agyeman
- Prempeh
- Osei
- Apea
- King
- king

  ______________ [Add] (input form)

"King" was added through the add button so was "king" but as I typed "king" again it failed to update and does not update afterwards no matter what I insert. Any ideas as to what is causing this?

Comment: I tried your code and this is what I could see in the console : `Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: name in names, Duplicate key: string:king, Duplicate value: king`.

Comment: Thank you for your input, however won't this just solve the problem for just the word 'king'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evening Israel,

You can't duplicate values in a repeater. To make it works, just add the following:

```
name in names track by $index
```

Or see it in action: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGzRKK

Hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome Arnaud, it worked perfectly. I suppose the reasonit worked is because it is tracking by index which cannot be a duplicate thanks @Eric for the console insight